# How to create a collection class which automatically adds new aggregation methods based on inherited class?

Tags: python, class, inheritance, properties

I have a class (`Team`) which is a collection of another class (`Player`). In the minimal example I simply have one `property` for `Player`, but my real world code has dozens of more complex properties, which I frequently add more to.

Currently every time I add a new `property` to `Player`, I need to manually add four new properties to `Team`, but I know there must be a better way to do this. I would like to have the `Team` class automatically add those four properties every time I create a new `property` in `Player`, vastly reducing the code I need to write, but I'm not sure the best way to go about this.

```
from statistics import mean, median


class Player:
    def __init__(self, name, age):
        self.name = name
        self._age = age

    @property
    def age(self):
        return self._age


class Team:
    def __init__(self, players):
        self.players = players

    @property
    def all_ages(self):
        return {player.name: player.age for player in self.players}

    @property
    def total_age(self):
        return sum([player.age for player in self.players])

    @property
    def average_age(self):
        return mean([player.age for player in self.players])
        
    @property
    def median_age(self):
        return median([player.age for player in self.players])


p1 = Player('John', 8)        
p2 = Player('Tim', 9)        
p3 = Player('Annie', 11)        
team = Team([p1, p2, p3])
```

Comment: There's no inheritance involved in your sample code — and I wouldn't expect any between a player and the team they belonged to. Collection classes generally don't inherit anything from the objects they contain (because doing so would severely limit their usefulness). Sounds to me like you are confusing "is-a" and "has-a" class relationships.

Answer (score 0):

As I said in a comment, there no inheritance involved between your collection class and the class of the object it contains. The means there will always be a certain amount of tedious repetitious coding required to set things — at least if you do it as shown below which makes use of class decorators — but once it's set-up, adding more properties should be relatively easy.

```
from statistics import mean, median


def make_stat_properties(team_cls, player_cls, name):
    storage_name = '_' + name

    @property
    def prop(self):
        return getattr(self, storage_name)
    @prop.setter
    def prop(self, value):
        setattr(self, storage_name, value)
    setattr(team_cls, name, prop)

    # Statistical methods.
    @property
    def all_func(self):
        return {getattr(player, 'name'): getattr(player, name) for player in self.players}
    func_name = f'all_{name}' if name.endswith('s') else f'all_{name}s'
    setattr(player_cls, func_name, all_func)

    @property
    def total_func(self):
        return sum(getattr(player, name) for player in self.players)
    setattr(player_cls, f'total_{name}', total_func)

    @property
    def average_func(self):
        return mean(getattr(player, name) for player in self.players)
    setattr(player_cls, f'average_{name}', average_func)

    @property
    def median_func(self):
        return median(getattr(player, name) for player in self.players)
    setattr(player_cls, f'median_{name}', median_func)

    return prop


class Team:
    def __init__(self, players):
        self.players = players


def stats_decorate(*names):
    def stats_prop_decorator(cls):
        """ Add stats properties to class. """
        for name in names:
            setattr(cls, name, make_stat_properties(cls, Team, name))
        def __init__(self, name, *args):
            self.name = name
            for name, arg in zip(names, args):
                setattr(self, f'_{name}', arg)
        setattr(cls, '__init__', __init__)
        return cls
    return stats_prop_decorator


@stats_decorate('age', 'goals')  # Add properties and related stat methods to class.
class Player:
    pass


if __name__ == '__main__':

    p1 = Player('John', 8, 1)
    p2 = Player('Tim', 9, 2)
    p3 = Player('Annie', 11, 3)
    team = Team([p1, p2, p3])

    print(f'{team.all_ages=}')
    print(f'{team.total_age=}')
    print(f'{team.average_age=:.2f}')
    print(f'{team.median_age=}')
    print()
    print(f'{team.all_goals=}')
    print(f'{team.total_goals=}')
    print(f'{team.average_goals=:.2f}')
    print(f'{team.median_goals=}')
```